# Send to Unreal without having to re-assemble the model?

Tags: unreal-engine

I have a building with multiple pieces in it.

[image]

I want to import it into Unreal Engine 5 but have all the components still grouped together so that I don't have to drag all the pieces into place in UE5.

When importing an FBX, UE5 breaks up the import into individual pieces.

[image]

How do I make it so I get a grouped model import?

Comment: I was having the same issue, exporting as Datasmith solved the issue.

Answer (score 3):

Its actually really simple. All you need to do is import the individual meshes, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> select all the meshes, and then drag them all in as a group. Selecting everything first and then dragging in will keep everything together.

[image]